# How much electricity does it take to create hydrogen from water depending on the water's pressure?

Tags: electricity, water, home-experiment, hydrogen, buoyancy

Imagine creating bubbles of hydrogen and oxygen underwater at a particular depth using electricity. Then reusing the energy of the bubbles going upward to the surface ( buoyancy ).

How is the energy required to split water to hydrogen and oxygen dependent on the water's pressure and temperature ?